# How would I write a method to turn a binary search tree (BST) into a sorted list for the values in the BST?

Tags: algorithm, scala, data-structures, binary-search-tree

So I have a binary search tree and need to produce a list with the BSTtoList method, but I'm not sure what the general steps are or what I have to do.

```
class BinarySearchTree[A](comparator: (A, A) => Boolean) {

  var root: BinaryTreeNode[A] = null

  def search(a: A): BinaryTreeNode[A] = {
    searchHelper(a, this.root)
  }

  def searchHelper(a: A, node: BinaryTreeNode[A]): BinaryTreeNode[A] = {
    if(node == null){
      null
    }else if(comparator(a, node.value)){
      searchHelper(a, node.left)
    }else if(comparator(node.value, a)){
      searchHelper(a, node.right)
    }else{
      node
    }
  }


  def BSTtoList: List[A] = {
    var sortedList = List()
    if (root.left != null) {
      sortedList :+ searchHelper(root.value, root.left).value

    }
    else if (root.right != null){
      sortedList :+ searchHelper(root.value, root.right).value
    }
    sortedList
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first think about how a BST works. At any given node, say with value x, all the nodes in the left subtree will have values < x and all nodes in the right subtree will have values > x. Thus, to return the sorted list of the subtree rooted at node x, you just have to return [sorted list of left subtree] + [x] + [sorted list of right subtree], so you just have to call BSTtoList recursively on the left and right subtrees, and then return the list described above. From there you just have to handle the base case of returning an empty list at a NULL node.

The above algorithm is O(N^2) time, and there's a better solution using tail recursion that runs in O(N) time, pseudocode for which:

```
def BSTtoList(root, accumulator):
    if root == NULL:
        return accumulator
    else:
        return BSTtoList(root.left_child, [root.value] + BSTtoList(root.right_child, accumulator)
```

Where BSTtoList is initially called with an empty list as the accumulator. This second solution works similarly to the first but is optimized by minimizing array merges (this version works best if the language used has O(1) insertion into the front of a list; implementation is a bit different if the language allows O(1) insertion into the back).